How to upload file in nextjs app router using multer
import multer from "multer"
const storage=multer.diskStorage({ destination:(req,file,cb)=>{ cb(null,"/public") },
filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
const fileName=Date.now()+file.filename cb(null,fileName) } })
const multerFilter=(req,File,cb)=>{ if(file.filename.mimetype.startsWith("image") { cb(null,true) }
else { cb(null,false) }
export const upload=multer({ storage:storage, fileFilter:multerFilter }) }
